# How to Extract video from bag file?

Tags: roslaunch, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am using ROS hydro on Ubuntu 12.04.
After using the command "**rosrun image_view extract_images _sec_per_frame:=0.01 image:={IMAGE_TOPIC_IN_BAGFILE}**" I'm having an error when executing"**ffmpeg -r -b -i frame%04d.jpg .avi**" The thing is I am not seeing the sequence of images after I play the bagfile.I ran "rosbag info" to obtain the topic in the bag file but when I run **"rosrun rqtgraph rqtgraph"** the /extract_image frame node is there all by itself.

When I follow the tutorials on http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Tutorials/Exporting%20image%20and%20video%20data  I get an error "*[FATAL] [1394583654.335465840]: Error opening file: play*".After replacing play by "--clock" or just removing "play" everything seemed to go just fine but there are no frames*.jpg in **/home/.ros**.
I feel like I'm lacking something.Can anyone help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/138566/how-to-extract-video-from-bag-file?/) by [Leyonce](https://answers.ros.org/users/13066/leyonce/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2014-03-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This was my image topic /front_camera/camera/image_raw/compressed.
This is what i had to do:

1. In a directory in which is writable (~/catkin_ws/bagfiles) type in the terminal  "**rosrun image_view extract_images image:=/front_camera/camera/image_raw _image_transport:=compressed** "
2. Then play the bagfile.(Though It can be done before or after)
   Then in the terminal in which  rosrun was executed the following appears:
   "*[ INFO] [1394806321.162974947]: Saved image frame0467.jpg*"
   The frames were made in that directory.
   process completed.

---

Originally posted by [Leyonce](https://answers.ros.org/users/13066/leyonce/) with karma: 97 on 2014-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pronik](https://answers.ros.org/users/13416/pronik/) on 2014-03-16**:
i'm also facing the same problem, can u pls explain step 1.

**Comment by [pronik](https://answers.ros.org/users/13416/pronik/) on 2014-03-16**:
pls help how to do it

**Comment by [Leyonce](https://answers.ros.org/users/13066/leyonce/) on 2014-03-17**:
@amentor.Sorry I did not reply earlier.Well,"~/catkin_ws" is my catkin workspace i just placed my bagfiles in there because of reasons.rosrun allows me to run the node extract_image which is in the package image view, and i identify the bagfile using its topic gotten using rosbag info.

**Comment by [Leyonce](https://answers.ros.org/users/13066/leyonce/) on 2014-03-17**:
anyways I guess that depending on the image topic you'll have to do an image_transport.Hope that helps.

**Comment by [pronik](https://answers.ros.org/users/13416/pronik/) on 2014-03-17**:
its not working for me. followed the same procedure, images are not being saved. the rostopic is same as your bag file.

**Comment by [Leyonce](https://answers.ros.org/users/13066/leyonce/) on 2014-03-19**:
@amentor.In which directory are you doing the rosrun?did i forget to mention that you need to play the bagfile after you perform the rosrun?please tell me exactly what you've done so i'll try it and maybe will I figure out what's wrong.